# How to get smoothed gabor filter output image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, gaussian

i asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141879/different-theta-for-gabor-filter-return-images-with-no-orientation) concerning the orientation of Gabor filter, and this question is about Gabor filter abut concerning aother point.

what i want to know is, why my output or the resultant image from Gabor filter inthe aforementioned line is different than the output image after applying the gabor filter in this image ?[image]

i applied gaussian kernel to smooth the image and then i applied the laplace operator on it and then i applied Gabor filter, but still the result images in the question i mentioned its link above, is still different than the gabor filter image in the second link i mentioned here.

why my gabor image looks different

Comment: It's strange to apply a Gabor filter after a laplacian operator.  You won't get the right image. For this, you need just Gaussian and Gabor.

Comment: @TomA would you please tell me why it is starnge to use gabor after laplacian operator. it is stated in a publication that, i have to apply gaussian then laplace then gabor

Comment: Because the Laplace filter and the Gabor filter do almost the same thing. It's like if you was doing a double integration.

Comment: @TomA thanks for your answer, but in the question i posted its link above, i have used gabor without laplace and the images were without orientation..i am misunderstood the orientation of gabor filter wrong

Comment: Please clarify your question. I read your two post and I catch nothing :/

Comment: @TomA what i mean is, the right image of the elephant in this post is the one after applying the gabor filter and it looks smooth, while the images i got in my question i posted its linke above, look not as smooth as the image of the elephant.

Comment: Where the Gabor elephant image come from? Are you sure that the filter was Gabor? Isn't it the parameters around?

Comment: @TomA sorry fo rthe late reply..the elephant image i found it in a website that offers gabor filter online visualisation and of course, the parameter i posted in my question is not that parameter applied on the elephant image